# -prune in find working without OR(-o) option - Unix

Tags: shell, scripting, aix

```
$pwd
/tmp
$touch 1.tst 2.tst
$mkdir inner_dir
$touch inner_dir/3.tst
$find . ! -name . -prune -name '*.tst'
1.tst
2.tst
```

I want to restrict 'find' to search only to the current directory for the files with 'tst' extension (I know this can be done with 'ls' command, but want to add other 'find' filters like mtime later on).
My question is how the above 'find' works?. 
Why doesn't the following work(with an OR option)?

```
find . ! -name . -prune -o -name '*.tst'
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm . See near the bottom, I think this applies to your case. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -prune
>               Always evaluates to the value True. Stops the descent of the current path name if it is a directory. If the -depth flag is specified, the -prune flag is
>               ignored.

I think if you play with it, you can figure out what it is doing.

e.g.

```
find . ! -name . -prune
```

gives

```
./1.tst
./2.tst
./d
```

We don't go down into ./d because of the prune -- "Stops the descent ...".  What is left is then filtered by the -name '*.tst' to be just the list files at the top directory.

HTH